# How to escape string for generated C++?

Tags: python, escaping, code-generation

I am writing python script which is generating C++ code based on the data.

I have python variable `string` which contains a string which can be composed
of characters like `"` or newlines.

What is the best way to escape this string for code generation?

Comment: Isn't this best solved by using a template engine like [jinja](http://jinja.pocoo.org/docs/templates/) which can already escape chars; I know I've done similar before when generating Java code - I'm aware that I may have misinterpreted your question.

Comment: Anyone know if [pycparser](https://github.com/eliben/pycparser) fills this use-case? This *seems* like something it *should* support, but its documentation is non-existent so I can't really tell...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The way I use is based on the observation that C++ strings basically
obey the same rules regarding charactes and escaping as Javascript/JSON string.

Python since version 2.6 has a built-in JSON library which can serialize Python
data into JSON. Therefore, the code is, assuming we don't need enclosing 
quotes, just as follows:

```
import json
string_for_printing = json.dumps(original_string).strip('"')
```

Comment: Except when there's Unicode characters in the string. Or when it ends with a quote. Also doesn't work for binary data. Escaping arbitrary data for C++ while keeping it readable is not as easy as it sounds - the last time I did this I just ended up turning every single byte into \xNN form.

Comment: @MattiVirkkunen of course for arbitrary data you want a hex dump like `xxd -i`. But if you can restrict to a reasonable character subset is there a tool for this?

Comment: @MattiVirkkunen C++ supports \unnnn and \Unnnnnnnn escape sequences.

Comment: Use a slice `[1:-1]` instead of `.strip('"')` if `original_string` starts with or ends with `"`.

Answer (score 3):

I use this code, so far without problems:

```
def string(s, encoding='ascii'):
   if isinstance(s, unicode):
      s = s.encode(encoding)
   result = ''
   for c in s:
      if not (32 <= ord(c) < 127) or c in ('\\', '"'):
         result += '\\%03o' % ord(c)
      else:
         result += c
   return '"' + result + '"'
```

It uses octal escapes to avoid all potentially problematic characters.

Answer (score 1):

We can do better using specifics of C found here (https://www.gnu.org/software/gnu-c-manual/gnu-c-manual.html#Character-Constants) and Python's built-in printable function:

```
def c_escape():
  import string
  mp = []
  for c in range(256):
    if c == ord('\\'): mp.append("\\\\")
    elif c == ord('?'): mp.append("\\?")
    elif c == ord('\''): mp.append("\\'")
    elif c == ord('"'): mp.append("\\\"")
    elif c == ord('\a'): mp.append("\\a")
    elif c == ord('\b'): mp.append("\\b")
    elif c == ord('\f'): mp.append("\\f")
    elif c == ord('\n'): mp.append("\\n")
    elif c == ord('\r'): mp.append("\\r")
    elif c == ord('\t'): mp.append("\\t")
    elif c == ord('\v'): mp.append("\\v")
    elif chr(c) in string.printable: mp.append(chr(c))
    else:
      x = "\\%03o" % c
      mp.append(x if c>=64 else (("\\%%0%do" % (1+c>=8)) % c, x))
  return mp
```

This has the advantage of now being a mapping from ordinal value of a character `ord(c)` to the exact string.  Using `+=` for strings is slow and bad practice, so this allows for `"".join(...)` which is far more performant in Python.  Not to mention, indexing a list/table is much faster than doing computations on characters each time through.  Also do not waste octal characters either by checking if less characters are needed.  However, to use this, you must verify the next character is not a `0` through `7` otherwise you must use the 3 digit octal format.

The table looks like:

```
[('\\0', '\\000'), ('\\1', '\\001'), ('\\2', '\\002'), ('\\3', '\\003'), ('\\4', '\\004'), ('\\5', '\\005'), ('\\6', '\\006'), '\\a', '\\b', '\\t', '\\n', '\\v', '\\f', '\\r', ('\\16', '\\016'), ('\\17', '\\017'), ('\\20', '\\020'), ('\\21', '\\021'), ('\\22', '\\022'), ('\\23', '\\023'), ('\\24', '\\024'), ('\\25', '\\025'), ('\\26', '\\026'), ('\\27', '\\027'), ('\\30', '\\030'), ('\\31', '\\031'), ('\\32', '\\032'), ('\\33', '\\033'), ('\\34', '\\034'), ('\\35', '\\035'), ('\\36', '\\036'), ('\\37', '\\037'), ' ', '!', '\\"', '#', '$', '%', '&', "\\'", '(', ')', '*', '+', ',', '-', '.', '/', '0', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9', ':', ';', '<', '=', '>', '\\?', '@', 'A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G', 'H', 'I', 'J', 'K', 'L', 'M', 'N', 'O', 'P', 'Q', 'R', 'S', 'T', 'U', 'V', 'W', 'X', 'Y', 'Z', '[', '\\\\', ']', '^', '_', '`', 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j', 'k', 'l', 'm', 'n', 'o', 'p', 'q', 'r', 's', 't', 'u', 'v', 'w', 'x', 'y', 'z', '{', '|', '}', '~', '\\177', '\\200', '\\201', '\\202', '\\203', '\\204', '\\205', '\\206', '\\207', '\\210', '\\211', '\\212', '\\213', '\\214', '\\215', '\\216', '\\217', '\\220', '\\221', '\\222', '\\223', '\\224', '\\225', '\\226', '\\227', '\\230', '\\231', '\\232', '\\233', '\\234', '\\235', '\\236', '\\237', '\\240', '\\241', '\\242', '\\243', '\\244', '\\245', '\\246', '\\247', '\\250', '\\251', '\\252', '\\253', '\\254', '\\255', '\\256', '\\257', '\\260', '\\261', '\\262', '\\263', '\\264', '\\265', '\\266', '\\267', '\\270', '\\271', '\\272', '\\273', '\\274', '\\275', '\\276', '\\277', '\\300', '\\301', '\\302', '\\303', '\\304', '\\305', '\\306', '\\307', '\\310', '\\311', '\\312', '\\313', '\\314', '\\315', '\\316', '\\317', '\\320', '\\321', '\\322', '\\323', '\\324', '\\325', '\\326', '\\327', '\\330', '\\331', '\\332', '\\333', '\\334', '\\335', '\\336', '\\337', '\\340', '\\341', '\\342', '\\343', '\\344', '\\345', '\\346', '\\347', '\\350', '\\351', '\\352', '\\353', '\\354', '\\355', '\\356', '\\357', '\\360', '\\361', '\\362', '\\363', '\\364', '\\365', '\\366', '\\367', '\\370', '\\371', '\\372', '\\373', '\\374', '\\375', '\\376', '\\377']
```

Example usage encoding some 4-byte integers as C-strings in little-endian byte order with new lines inserted every 50 characters:
v

```
mp = c_escape()
vals = [30,50,100]
bytearr = [z for i, x in enumerate(vals) for z in x.to_bytes(4, 'little', signed=x<0)]
"".join(mp[x] if not type(mp[x]) is tuple else mp[x][1 if not i == len(bytearr)-1 and bytearr[i+1] in list(range(ord('0'), ord('7')+1)) else 0] + ("\"\n\t\"" if (i % 50) == 49 else "") for i, x in enumerate(bytearr))

#output: '\\36\\0\\0\\0002\\0\\0\\0d\\0\\0\\0'
```